# Элементарный почтовый сервер

Tags: linux, ubuntu, postfix

Суть вот в чём. В сети есть две машины. На одной Ubuntu 16.04 с LAMP. На второй Windows 7 + специальная программа для работы с прибором, который тоже подключён к этому компьютеру. Эта программа к прибору по завершении работы может отправлять электронное письмо на указанный адрес.

Хотелось бы, чтобы письма отправлялись по сети (LAN) на компьютер с Ubuntu и записывались в БД (LAMP уже стоит). Задача на словах простая, но т.к. с linux практически никогда не работал, вообще не представляю как тут быть.

Дома на виртуальной машине поставил себе ubuntu. Установил postfix как local delivery only. А что дальше? Как подключить к БД? Или он вообще с БД не работает? Какие данные нужно указывать, чтобы хоть тот же встроенный почтовый клиент настроить на работу с этой почтой? Так толком и не разобрался.

Помогите, пожалуйста. Как быть? Или есть другие варианты?

Comment: [/etc/aliases pipe](https://www.google.ru/search?ie=UTF-8&hl=ru&q=%2Fetc%2Faliases%20pipe) — этой простой и древней возможностью сейчас очень редко пользуются. ставлю десять пачек чаю против шкуры дохлого бизона, что вы, скорее всего, в конце концов также пойдёте каким-нибудь другим, значительно более сложным, зато новомодным, путём.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю задачу, для Вас критично, что данные, снятые с прибора, отправляются по eMaill. И Вы не хотите это изменять. Тогда ни апач, ни PHP Вам не помогут.

Однако, любой почтовый клиент (для Убунту, к примеру - Evolution) именно для того и предназначен, что бы принимать почту. В настройках этого клиента задаёте, что бы он проверял почту, к примеру, каждые 5 минут. Если у выбранного Вами почтового клиента такой возможности нет, просто запускаете его периодически, с помощью cron.

Итак, письма приняты и лежат в почтовой БД клиента. Вам хочется переложить их а БД MsSQL? Но ведь, наверняка, вы желаете передать в MySQL не всё письмо, а только данные, которые в нём содержатся? Ну, может быть ещё, время отправки.

Тут уже придётся работать Вам. Надо написать программу, которая будет просматривать почтовую БД вашего почтового клиента и обрабатывать содержащиеся в ней письма, доставая из них интересующую информацию.

Для того, что бы получить доступ к почтовой БД (которая в разных почтовых клиентах может быть организована совершенно по разному), нужно воспользоваться библиотекой разработчика, которая, как правило, имсеется для каждого клиента.  Возможно, Вам пригодится библиотека evolution-mapi.

Вот здесь (https://www.linux.com/learn/use-evolution-connect-microsoft-exchange-linux) описывается решение похожей задачи - связь Evolution с микрософтным Exchange.

Но, как мне кажется, Вашу задачу можно решить довольно просто и без почтовых клиентов вообще. В Perl и Phyton есть очень хорошие библиотеки для работы с почтой.

Comment: Я не знаю, где вы прочитали, что мне нужно получать почту почтовым клиентов и т.п. И что потом нужно работать в базой этого почтового клиента. Я говорила об отправке по сети без участия интернета и сборщков почты. Мне просто нужно, чтобы ubuntu был способен принимать почту по сети и хранил эти данные в mysql. Только этого и ничего больше. Спасибо, конечно, за ответ, но предложенное вами не вариант. Особенно использование интернета.

Comment: **чтобы ubuntu был способен принимать почту** - Ubuntu это НЕ почтовая программа. Это название одного из дистрибутивов Linux. Сама по себе  постановка такого вопроса бессмысленна. Вроде того, что "Хочу, что бы город ловил рыбу".  Рыбу ловят рыбаки, живущие в городе. Точно так же и принимать почту может программа, специально для этого написанная - почтовый клиент. Такие программы есть в составе Ubuntu. Не желаете их использовать - пишите свою. Других вариантов нет...

Comment: **Я говорила об отправке по сети без участия интернета** - сети классифицируется по многим характеристикам. В частности СЕТЬ (общее понятие) бывает локальная (интранет) и глобальная (интернет). Устроены они абсолютно ОДИНАКОВО, просто интернет от интранета отеляются специальным компьютером, который называется роутер.

Comment: Вы опять о почтовых программах. На них мир сошёлся клином? Да, я возможно допускаю неточности, но всё же. Попробую ещё раз. Идея у меня такая - отправлять письмо электронное по LAN на компьютер с Ubuntu. На стороне Ubuntu принимать почту и записывать в mysql. Всё. Я писал, что пробовал использовать postfix, однако так и не нашёл нигде статьи, которая описывали бы то, что нужно. Везде описывается полное разворачивание почтового сервера со всеми протоколами (POP, IMAP, SMTP), пересылка почты и др. Получать почту по SMPT может postfix сам по себе.Но как быть с mysql и как на него отправить почту?

Comment: **Вы опять о почтовых программах. На них мир сошёлся клином?** - любая программа, работающая с электронной почтой, называется "почтовой программой". Все почтовые программы делятся на две категории: 1) Почтовый сервер 2) Почтовый клиент. Процесс доставки письма выполняется в три этапа: 1) Почтовый клиент-отправитель формирует текст письма и передаёт его по сети (неважно - какой) на почтовый сервер. 2) Почтовый сервер принимает переданное письмо и храните его столько, сколько нужно для доставки адресату. 3) Почтовый клиент-получатель связывается с почтовым сервером и забирает письмо.

Comment: **пробовал использовать postfix** - официальное его название "Агент передач почты". Т.е. это не просто почтовый сервер, а он ещё умеет сортировать почту и рассылать её дальше, по другим направлениям. Зачем Вам это надо?! Вам даже не нужен почтовый сервер - никакой!

Comment: Спасибо за просвящение. Я и спрашивал, может есть другие варианты. Вы говорите что есть. И что же это и как с ним быть?

Comment: **может есть другие варианты** - лично для меня (поскольку я программист), самый простой вариант - написать свою программульку. Она не сложная будет - приём письма, выделение данных и загрузка в MySQL, Возможно, что-то такое уже есть, но я не слышал... Есть такая штука, как imapsync, она предназначена для перекачки почтовых архивов с сервера на сервер. Но, думаю, тут она не пригодится :-(

Comment: Вот, что-то очень похожее на Вашу проблему:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8322740/import-xml-file-into-mysql-database-when-received-on-email

Answer (score 0):

exim + dbmail + mysql на убунте - ровно то, что, как вы написали ("Хотелось бы, чтобы письма отправлялись по сети (LAN) на компьютер с Ubuntu и записывались в БД"), вы хотите.

Однако меня терзают смутные подозрения, что на самом деле вы хотите не совсем то, что написали. Особенно в части "записывались в БД".